# $X=$ number of emails with Poisson($\lambda$) distribution Each email classified ind. as spam with prob. $p$. $Y =$ #spam. Find $E(Y)$ and Dist, $Y$

Tags: probability-theory

My thought was that since the $\mathbb E(X) = \lambda$, so then $\mathbb E(Y)$ would be the sum from $i=0$ to $X$ of $\lambda p$. Since $\lambda$ is the number of expected emails, then $\lambda p$ would be the probability of spam emails with probability $p$?

Answer (score 0):

$\newcommand{E}{\operatorname{E}}$This is a fairly standard exercise.  Notice that $Y\mid X\sim\mathrm{Binomial}(X,p)$, so
$$
E(Y) = \E(\E(Y\mid X)) = \E(Xp)=p\E(X) = p\lambda.
$$

Next, we have
\begin{align}
\Pr(Y=y) & = \E(\Pr(Y=y\mid X)) \\[8pt]
& = \E\left( \binom X y p^y(1-p)^{X-y} \right) \\[8pt]
& = p^y \sum_{x=0}^\infty \binom x y (1-p)^{x-y} \Pr(X=x) \\[8pt]
& = p^y \sum_{x=0}^\infty \binom x y (1-p)^{x-y} \frac{\lambda^x e^{-\lambda}}{x!} \\[8pt]
& = \frac {(p\lambda)^y e^{-p\lambda}} {y!} \sum_{x=y}^\infty \frac{(\lambda(1-p))^x}{(x-y)!}e^{-(1-p)\lambda} \\[8pt]
& = \frac {(p\lambda)^y e^{-p\lambda}} {y!} \underbrace{\sum_{w=0}^\infty \frac{((1-p)\lambda)^w}{w!} e^{-(1-p)\lambda} }_{\text{This }=1.}
\end{align}
So you get a Poisson distribution.

If this is a homework assignment, do not simply write what I wrote above.  Instead include some explanations of steps.

Comment: How did you know that Y|X ~ Binomial (X, p)

Comment: @user180069 : The binomial distribution is the distribution of the number of successes in a fixed (i.e. non-random) number of independent trials with the same probability of success on each trial. If you're finding the conditional distribution of the number of spam emails given $X$, then you're treating $X$ as non-random in that context, and $X$ is the number of trials.